# How to get Sharepoint List using c#

Tags: c#, sharepoint-2010

How to get fields values from a particular list item.In my case i want to get all form fileds of Workplan list.Actually i want to get Workplan all list item and insert to sharepoint 2013 associated database.

[image: example]

I try the following code.

```
string strUrl = "http://example.com/default.aspx";
using (SPSite site = new SPSite(strUrl))
{
    using (SPWeb web = site.OpenWeb())
    {                 

        SPList list = web.Lists[52];
        SPQuery myquery = new SPQuery();
        myquery.Query = "";        
        SPListItemCollection items = list.GetItems(myquery);                

        foreach (SPListItem item in items)
        {
            if (item != null)
            {
                var Name = item.ListItems.Fields.List;
                Console.WriteLine("Name is :" + Name);
            }
        }  
    }
}
```

Comment: Would you mind accepting an answer?

Answer (score 9):

This is the easiest way I can think of using Server Object Model:

```
string strUrl = "http://example.com";                
using(SPSite oSite = new SPSite(strUrl))
{        
   using(SPWeb oWeb = oSite.OpenWeb())
   {
      SPList list = oWeb.Lists["Workplan"];

       foreach(SPField field in list.Fields)
       {
           Console.WriteLine(field.Title);
       }
    }            
}
```

Btw, as for your site-URL `"http://example.com/default.aspx"` it is enough to do it like `"http://example.com"`.

For more information on Sharepoint I recommend using [this site](https://sharepoint.stackexchange.com/) in the future.

Comment: Thank you for your answer. This worked beautifully, can you please include any documentation you found.

Answer (score 2):

```
using (SPSite site = new SPSite("URL")
     {
        using (SPWeb web = site.OpenWeb("sitecollection/subsite"))
        {
         //to get specific list type
           string listUrl = "/sites/sitecollection/subsite/Lists/Announcements";
           SPList list = web.GetList(listUrl);
           Console.WriteLine("List URL: {0}", list.RootFolder.ServerRelativeUrl);
        }
     }
```

//To get all lists from spweb use this:

```
SPSite oSiteCollection = SPContext.Current.Site;
using(SPWebCollection collWebs = oSiteCollection.AllWebs)
{
foreach (SPWeb oWebsite in collWebs)
{
    SPListCollection collSiteLists = oWebsite.Lists;
    foreach (SPList oList in collSiteLists)
    {
        //get your each list here
    }
    oWebsite.Dispose();
}
}
```

Comment: SPSite oSiteCollection = SPContext.Current.Site; throws exception Object reference not set to an instance of an object.

Comment: I got the name of List URL: Lists/Workplan .Now how to get all its fields.

Comment: Why do you avoid the using-statement in the last part and dispose the web-object manually although you are using it in the rest of your code.

Comment: @bodycountPP it depends how you want to write your code, no matter how you implement the code, but oWebsite must be disposed. This can be done Using statement or you can dispose it manually. Using statement is shortcut of Try{}finally{yourobject.dispose();}

Comment: Just to remind you missed a closing bracket in this line:
using (SPSite site = new SPSite("URL")    )

Comment: @RAY stack answers are not for copy-paste.. I guess. This is just to help the users so that they get idea and find their solutions. So, I think comment like this should be discarded. Not happy with your comment